# $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ be Riemann Integrable , then $g_n(x):= \int _a^x f(t)\cos(nt)dt$ converges uniformly , on $[a,b]$ , to the zero function ?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, soft-question, uniform-convergence

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ be Riemann Integrable ; define a sequence of functions $\{g_n\}$ with domain $[a,b]$ as $g_n(x):= \int _a^x f(t)\cos(nt)dt , \forall x \in [a,b] , \forall n \in \mathbb N$ . Then is it true that $\{g_n\}$ converges uniformly , on $[a,b]$ , to the zero function ? If not , then what extra condition(s) do we need to impose on $f$ to make it happen ?

Comment: You may refer to the [*Riemann-Lebesgue lemma*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma). The idea of proof is to approximate $f$ by nice functions with which the claim becomes easy to verify.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If f is Riemann integrable we can uniformly approximate it by step functions. Then we can use this uniform convergence to swap the limits with the integrals. Hope this allows you to make some headway.

Comment: Thinking about it more, this question has quite a few steps. It may be necessary to first show that the result holds for the case when f is a step function (which should be easy by direct calculation) and then to show that the limit when f is arbitrary is the same as that of the case when we use the step function which approximates it.

Answer (score 0):

We know by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma that $g_n$ converges pointwise to $0$ on $[a,b]$. Since $f$ is Riemann integrable, it is bounded. Say $|f(x)|\le M$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Then
$$
|g_n(x)|\le M(b-a),\quad a\le x\le b,
$$
and
$$
|g_n(x)-g_n(y)|=\Bigl|\int_x^yf(t)\cos(n\,t)\,dt\Bigr|\le M\,|x-y|,\quad a\le x,y\le b.
$$
The sequence $\{g_n\}$ is uniformly bounded and equicontinuous. ¿Can you follow from here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea:

- Prove that $\{g_n\}$ converges pointwise to the zero function on $[a,b]$.
- Prove that $\{g_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence of the Banach space of Riemann-integrable functions on $[a,b]$ endowed with the sup norm.

Hint: For all real number $x$ and for all integers $n$ and $m$, 
$$\cos(nx)-\cos(mx)=2\sin\left(\dfrac{n+m}2x\right)\sin\left(\dfrac{n-m}2x\right)$$